# TenantNotAvailableException, when trying to call business partner from s4 CF SDK

Tags: s4sdk

I am trying with deploying the basic business partner app on my local tomee, and i am getting the below error "TenantNotAvailableException: Failed to get current tenant: tenant not available" while calling http://localhost:8080/businesspartners

[image: Error while calling /businesspartners]

what i tried is to check the "destinations" variable and its seems to be accessible from application, How do i resolve this? Am i missing any configuration?

Thanks,
Girish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a bug in the OData call. We will look into this and update this answer once it is fixed.

As a workaround (for non-productive use cases only!) you can set the `ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER` environment variable to `true`. This will provide a mocked tenant in case to tenant could be identified by the SDK. In [step 7](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/18/step-7-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-secure-your-application-on-sap-cloud-platform-cloudfoundry/) of our blog series you will learn how to setup an approuter to provide you such a tenant so that you can remove the variable.

Comment: Thanks Christoph Schubert, this work for me after deploying locally.