# Tenant Not availalbe exception despite the use of the workaround

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have implented GetAllBusinessPartnerCommand and also customized the code in the BusinessPartnerServlet. When I try to call the application with the customized code, I always get this error.

Code GetAllBusinessPartnersCommand

```
package com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.commands;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

import com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples.BusinessPartnerServlet;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.logging.CloudLoggerFactory;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.frameworks.hystrix.HystrixUtil;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.connectivity.ErpCommand;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.Order;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.namespaces.businesspartner.BusinessPartner;
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.services.DefaultBusinessPartnerService;

public class GetAllBusinessPartnersCommand extends ErpCommand<List<BusinessPartner>>{
    
    private static final Logger logger = CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(BusinessPartnerServlet.class);
    public static final String CATEGORY_PERSON ="1";

   

public GetAllBusinessPartnersCommand() {
    
     super(HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandSetter(
             GetAllBusinessPartnersCommand.class,
             HystrixUtil.getDefaultErpCommandProperties().withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(10000)));
    
}

    @Override
    protected List<BusinessPartner> run() throws Exception {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new DefaultBusinessPartnerService().getAllBusinessPartner()
                .select(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER,
                        BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME,
                        BusinessPartner.FIRST_NAME,
                        BusinessPartner.IS_MALE,
                        BusinessPartner.IS_FEMALE,
                        BusinessPartner.CREATION_DATE)
                .filter(BusinessPartner.BUSINESS_PARTNER_CATEGORY.eq(CATEGORY_PERSON))
                .orderBy(BusinessPartner.LAST_NAME, Order.ASC)
                .execute();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected List<BusinessPartner> getFallback() {
    logger.warn("Fallback called because of exception:",
    getExecutionException());
    return Collections.emptyList();
        }
}
```

n the following you can see the commands and the offered workaround for the problem set ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER=true.  Before testing I checked if all variables are set correctly and set ALLOW_MOCKED_AUTH_HEADER=true again because I set it too early before.

After this steps i build my project like i always do and get the error from above when im calling the service. I also read this post where someone have the same problem and used the mentioned workaround. But this doesnt work for me and i have no clue why. [TenantNotAvailableException, when trying to call business partner from s4 CF SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636956/tenantnotavailableexception-when-trying-to-call-business-partner-from-s4-cf-sdk/55646498#55646498)

[error when call page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15jla.png)

[Starting mock-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXBJD.png)
[set variables and workaround plus check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pM9J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately *SAP Cloud SDK* `2.x` is no longer supported. Please use our [migration guide](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/s4sdk-migration-v3.html) to move to the latest version `3.43.0` You can find my [blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/01/migrate-to-version-3.0.0-of-the-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java/) on this topic too. If you face any issues, please create another StackOverflow question (with tag `sap-cloud-sdk`) or comment to the blog post. For more details, please find our [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/).